# Dualizing sheaf on a Cohen-Macaulay variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $X$ be a Cohen-Macaulay variety over $k$, i.e. all local rings are Cohen-Macaulay (perhaps this can later be generalized). What is the dualizing sheaf on $X$, what is its central/characterizing property and can one write it down explicitly?

I'm asking this in such a naive way (knowing that there is a vast literature on this) because I have the following problem: I'm (obviously) not an expert in algebraic geometry and came across a definition stating that the dualizing sheaf of $X$ is $\omega_X := j_* \omega_{X_s}$, where $j:X_s \rightarrow X$ is the inclusion of the smooth locus $X_s$ of $X$ and $\omega_{X_s} := \mathrm{det}(\Omega_{X_s/k}^1)$. I can take this of course as a definition (it is pretty easy, and I also know something about dualizing sheaves on smooth varieties) but I don't know what the central properties of this sheaf in this setting are. I know that there is Grothendieck-Verdier-Neeman(-more names) duality and while browsing through Hartshorne's book *Residues and Duality* I tried to deduce this definition from the abstract "nonsense" but I failed. I know that there exists this very general duality and that there happens something in the Cohen-Macaulay case but this was over my head!

Amnon Neeman defines in his article *Derived categories and Grothendieck duality* a *dualizing complex* of a noetherian and separated scheme $X$ to be an object $\mathcal{J} \in \mathbf{D}^b( \mathrm{Coh}(X))$ such that $\mathbb{R}\mathcal{H}om(-,\mathcal{J}):\mathbf{D}^b(\mathrm{Coh}(X))^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{D}^b(\mathrm{Coh}(X))$ is an (triangulated) equivalence. Is it correct that if $X$ is a (separated?) noetherian Cohen-Macaulay scheme the sheaf defined above is a dualizing complex in this sense and that this is the characterizing property I was asking for? This is the only idea I have so far...

Comment: I think $X$ would have to be normal in addition to Cohen-Macaulay
for this formula to work. 
There are many experts who can explain this better than I could.
In one sentence that the dualizing sheaf (or complex) is the thing which makes the Grothendieck-Serre duality theorem work; it would
be unique up to isomorphism if it exists.


Comment: Uniqueness of $\omega$ up to shift & twist by line bundle when $X$ conn'd. For smooth $X$, *any* line bundle is dualizing; top-diff'tls makes duality "explicit" via residues. CM equiv. to $\omega$ being sheaf (in some degree). For CM $X$ and $j:U \rightarrow X$ open with complement of codim $\ge 2$, want $\omega \rightarrow j_{\ast}(\omega|_U)$ an isom. By SGA2, III, Cor. 3.5, need depth$(\omega_x) > 1$ for $x \in X-U$. Crux: $\omega_x$ satisfies *local duality*, so by Ext depth criterion same as $H^i_x(k(x))=0$ for $i \ge {\rm{dim}}O_x-1$ ($> 0$!). Verify via excision (cf. SGA2, II, Cor. 4)!

Comment: I was hoping you'd jump in, but now I'm confused. $\omega=f^!\mathcal{O}_{spec k}$ is only unique up to shift & twist?

Comment: @Donu: the formula you give is a dualizing object, but not the only one. The property that defines a dualizing object $R^{\bullet}$ in $D^b_c(X)$ is finite injective dimension and on $D^b_c(X)$ the functor $\mathbf{D} = {\mathbf{R}}\mathcal{H}om^{\bullet}(\cdot,R^{\bullet})$ satisfies the "double duality" map ${\rm{id}} \rightarrow \mathbf{D} \circ \mathbf{D}$ (which makes sense due to the finite injective dimension hypothesis) is an isom. By inspection, applying shift and line bundle twist has no effect! Remarkable fact is that this is the only ambiguity, for connected $X$.

Comment: @Donu Arapura (and BCnrd can correct me): in general, dualizing sheaf/complex (if it exists) is unique up to twist by a line bundle and a shift. If you deal with a scheme of finite type over a field, there is a natural choice (among all possible dualizing sheaves) that you suggest: $f^!O_{spec(k)}$.  

Comment: By the way, in response to last question of Arminius: 
`separated' does include affine varieties. I believe semi-separatedness actually works just as well.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks. I guess I was using a narrower definition. Hopefully this hasn't made things worse for Arminius: People in birational geometry often call $j_*\Omega_X^{\dim X}$ the canonical sheaf, which perhaps is less ambiguous.

Comment: @t3suji: Of course! I was somewhere else...
@Donu: I think it is $j_*\Omega_X^{\dim X}$ as long as $X$ is irreducible!?
@all others: I will see if I can understand your comments...

Comment: @t3suji: 'semi-separated' was perhaps what I was looking for. But except for separated schemes I don't know of any semi-separated ones. Is there some condition that for a morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ of varieties into a semi-separated/separated/affine variety ensures that $X$ is also semi-separated?

Comment: Arminius: Not convinced. If $X$ is the $y^2=x^3$, $j_*\Omega_X^1$ isn't even coherent.

Comment: Donu is right, you probably want normality if you want to do that.  

Another characterization in the affine case that you might find useful is the following:

If $X$ is an affine CM equidimensional subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^n$, then you can define a dualizing sheaf to be $Ext^{n-dim X}(O_X, O_{\mathbb{A}^n})$.  Something like this is stated in Hartshorne's algebraic geometry and it's certainly is Residues and duality (as well as many other sources --
 Brian Conrad's book).  

Comment: @Donu, Karl: Okay, as I don't know exactly what I want (the reason for asking this question), I am not qualified to comment on that. At least in Liu Quing's book the canonical sheaf on a _smooth_ variety $X$ is defined as $\mathrm{det}\Omega_X^1$ (6.4.2). But I'll try to put things together...

Comment: The pushforward formula is only correct when the open set has complement with codimension $\ge 2$, also used in the vanishing aspect of the local duality argument in my initial comment. In general I don't like to say the formulas (pushforward, Ext on an affine space, etc.) are the "definition" of a dualizing sheaf, but rather a way to compute one (coupled with a suitable trace map, which can be quite hard to make "explicit" away from simple examples). A dualizing object yields a "codimension function", and demanding it match usual codimension (can always be done) eliminates shift ambiguity.